# Chat tutorials?

Tags: discussion

I recently took a bit of stick for suggesting that the [Minkowski metric was an easy way to understand special relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/134417/is-special-relativity-a-special-case-of-general-relativity-qualitatively/134422#134422), and this morning I suspect I've managed to be more [confusing than helpful discussing this with Floris](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/110669/is-gravitational-time-dilation-different-from-other-forms-of-time-dilation/110675#comment275598_110675). I wonder if this is the sort of issue that site members would be interested in discussing in a chat session.

My only reservation is that I'm not sure how well suited the SE chat is to this sort of thing; for example does it allow the posting of equations?

Assuming there's any appetite for the idea, I wonder if there's a better way to do it than the SE chat.

Comment: MathJaX in chat requires [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/should-chat-have-tex-support/3297#3297), but after that, there are equations in chat. Also, you could always create your own rooms for discussing something if you do (for whatever reason) not want to flood the main chat with it. On the idea itself, I'm not quite sure what you have in mind - set aside a dedicated time where people are encouraged to come to that chat and ask questions?

Comment: I definitely would like to encourage you do to these things in the main chat, John :) It's never all that busy anyways (me and @Phonon recently filled it up with chess talk for a while)!

Comment: To be honest this was a spur of the moment idea and I haven't really thought it through. I'll be joining the scheduled chat tomorrow, so maybe if anyone's interested in specific topics we could try discussing it then. However, after some thought I'm not sure how well it will work. For example it would be nice to be able to sketch drawings to explain things, and of course chat doesn't have any way to do this.

Comment: You can draw it in Paint and then upload it from the CPU

Comment: I am sorry that I had deleted my side of the referenced conversation before becoming aware that it was an example of how we sometimes abuse comments...